# Function check session attribute with jstl

Tags: java, jsp, web, jstl

I want add function return type of access in my session , its work with this code but i want use jstl in jsp , can you offer any idea ?

```
<%
if (String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("acces")).equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {
%>
  <li class="page_item"><a href="Admin">Admin</a></li>
<%
} else {
%>
<%
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSTL core taglib

```xml
<c:set var="cond" value='${"admin".equalsIgnoreCase(sessionScope.acces)}'/>
<c:if test="${cond}">
  <li class="page_item"><a href="Admin">Admin</a></li>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!cond}">
</c:if>
```